# how to set up storybook alias

Tags: webpack, alias, storybook

I'm going to use the storybook in the `yarn-berry`, `react`, and `typescript` environment.

So I use `storybook/react-webpack5`.

When I use the storybook in a way that I specify the path myself, it works, but when I specify alias in Storybook setting file `main.ts`, the storybook does not work.

I set alias to `webpack` and `tsconfig.json` as follows.

`webpack.common.js`

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js'],
    alias: {
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
      '@styles': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles'),
      '@apis': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/apis'),
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
      '@pages': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages'),
      '@constants': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/constants'),
      '@hooks': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/hooks'),
      '@utils': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils'),
      '@public': path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
      '@config': path.resolve(__dirname, 'config.ts'),
    },
  },
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
"{
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@styles/*": ["src/styles/*"],
      "@apis/*": ["src/apis/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
      "@public/*": ["public/*"],
      "@config": ["config.ts"]
    }
},
```

`main.ts`

```
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.resolve?.plugins?.push(
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, '../tsconfig.json'),
      }),
    );
    return {
      ...config,
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|webp)$/,
            type: 'asset',
          },
          {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: ['@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader'],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)?$/,
            type: 'asset',
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
```

And the following error occurs

`Error: Cannot find module '@components/Header'`

I think the alias setting is wrong in main.ts. Please let me know where it is wrong.